# why does SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() returning null?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I am trying to get ID generated by last Insert function. I understand very little about Scope and Session. But by reading blogs and other sources, I understood that, I should use Scope_Identity() function. But I am getting null value. Here is my code :

```
 public int InsertUser(string username, string gender, string agegroup, string email, int partnerID, string userType)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "Insert into tblUser (username,gender,agegroup,email,partnerid,usertype) values (@username,@gender,@age,@email,@partnerid,@usertype)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _dbConnection.getCon());
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", agegroup);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partnerid", partnerID);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertype", userType);
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            query = "select scope_identity() as id";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, _dbConnection.getCon());
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);// dt is showing no value in it
            return 1;// This should return ID

        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try appending `SELECT scope_identity()` to your first query and then capture the identity using `var identity = cmd.ExecuteScalar()` instead of running `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: This one worked. Thanks.  I thought of it, but I stuck to previous one because, If I run select scope_identity() statement in sql editor after Insert statement, it was working.

Comment: The problem lies in batching; the ADO.NET api will wrap parameterised INSERT statements in sp_executesql, and scope_identity will only return the identity if executed within the same scope.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.As, I understood, Session means -executed queries in same Opened and Closed Connection. And Scope in terms of Tables. Can you tell me what is exact meaning of Scope and Session in SQL terms?

Comment: Hard to explain in a comment thread.. but here's some recommended reading : [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315(v=sql.90).aspx).